# How can I split this excel file into two data frames?

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: excel spreadsheet]

When I try and load this excel spreadsheet into a dataframe I get a lot of NAN due to all the random white space in the file. I'd really like to split class I and class A from this excel file into two seperate pandas dataframe

In:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
excel_file = 'EXAMPLE.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header=8)
print(df)
sys.exit()
```

Out:

```
               Class I  Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7              Class A  Unnamed: 9 Unnamed: 10  Unnamed: 11 Unnamed: 12
0                 Date         NaN   column 1         NaN   column 2         NaN         NaN         NaN                 Date         NaN    column 1          NaN    column 2
1  2019-12-31 00:00:00         NaN          1         NaN          A         NaN         NaN         NaN  2019-12-31 00:00:00         NaN           A          NaN           1
2  2020-01-01 00:00:00         NaN          2         NaN          B         NaN         NaN         NaN  2020-01-01 00:00:00         NaN           B          NaN           2
3  2020-01-02 00:00:00         NaN          3         NaN          C         NaN         NaN         NaN  2020-01-02 00:00:00         NaN           C          NaN           3
4  2020-01-03 00:00:00         NaN          4         NaN          D         NaN         NaN         NaN  2020-01-03 00:00:00         NaN           D          NaN           4
5  2020-01-04 00:00:00         NaN          5         NaN          E         NaN         NaN         NaN  2020-01-04 00:00:00         NaN           E          NaN           5
6  2020-01-05 00:00:00         NaN          6         NaN          F         NaN         NaN         NaN  2020-01-05 00:00:00         NaN           F          NaN           6
7  2020-01-06 00:00:00         NaN          7         NaN          G         NaN         NaN         NaN  2020-01-06 00:00:00         NaN           G          NaN           7
8  2020-01-07 00:00:00         NaN          8         NaN          H         NaN         NaN         NaN  2020-01-07 00:00:00         NaN           H          NaN           8
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, Otherwise, looking at your question, it is really difficult to help you

Comment: Just made a fix!

Comment: Do you want the first 8 columns in one dataframe, and the last 5 in another?

Comment: Sorry! I'd like the the first set of columns:[Date, Column 1, Column 2] in one dataframe, and the second set of columns:[Date, Column 1, Column 2] in another one.

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for you can accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the parameter `usecols`. From the documentation:

> If list of int, then indicates list of column numbers to be parsed.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file,usecols=[0,2,4])
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file,usecols=[8,10,12])
```

This should create two dataframes with the columns you want.